# SharePoint online redirect old site to new site

Tags: sharepoint-online, redirect

I have created new site in SharePoint online say /sites/new/ and now i want to redirect all users visiting site /sites/old/ to the newly created site.

I know there are options to achieve it through Script editor web part and content editor web part. Is there any other OOB way to redirect ?

Second, is there any way in SharePoint online through some OOB web part that will redirect users of specific AD or SPO group to specific site ? I figured there is a user redirect web part in on-premise but not sure about SPO.

Could someone please add detail to the asked questions ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below steps :

1. Go to the gear button, click on the site settings
2. Under look and feel, click on page layouts and site templates
3. Create a new page in the old site
4. Change the layout of this new page to the redirect layout
5. Fill in the information of the new URL (Type in where the space is highlighted below)
6. Set this new page as the welcome page

Another temporary solution would be to add a JavaScript redirect code onto the page like the below image.

```
'<script type=”text/javascript”>
 <!–
  window.location=”http://<address of the new and improved site>”
  //–>
 </script>,
```

Reference URL:

[How to redirect users to a new site in SharePoint Online](https://technologyblog.rsmus.com/it-infrastructure/how-to-redirect-users-to-a-new-site-in-sharepoint-online/)

[How to redirect as page on SharePoint Online (Office 365)](https://www.google.com/amp/s/lelandholmquest.wordpress.com/2015/04/01/how-to-redirect-as-page-on-sharepoint-online-office-365/amp/)

Comment: Hi - if this has helped you, could you please mark this as answered, so that it will help to the upcoming visitors.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. This means there is no OOB way to redirect users to target site other than injecting JavaScript code into the pages, right ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no OOB ways to redirect sites in SharePoint Online.

For your requirements, I think you'd better change the old site adress to the new site adress. You could read this article for more:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/change-site-address

Comment: Han

Thank you very much for taking out time to reply this thread. I have gone through the shared article but in my case i need a redirection. The site hosted at new URL is completely different from the old site. I tried to rename the old site to free the reserved name and when i entered the old site name to the new site, assuming renaming the old should free the old site name but i got message this site name is already reserved. This means the only option i have now is to inject the script either through script editor web part or CSR to redirect users to new site.